# Save Excel file as CSV without losing special characters β

Tags: vbscript

I have a file with `β` charcters. While converting Excel to CSV, these are converted to `?`. I am doing it via ADODB.

```
Dim CONNECTION1
Set CONNECTION1 = WScript.CreateObject("ADODB.Connection")
CONNECTION1.Open "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=D:\Test.xlsx;Extended Properties=""Excel 12.0;HDR=YES;"""

Dim RECORDSET1
Set RECORDSET1 = WScript.CreateObject("ADODB.Recordset")
RECORDSET1.Open "SELECT * FROM [Sheet1$]", CONNECTION1, 3, 1

Dim CONNECTION2
Set CONNECTION2 = WScript.CreateObject("ADODB.Connection")
CONNECTION2.Open "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=D:\Test.csv;Extended Properties=""Text;HDR=Yes;FMT=Delimited;CharacterSet=65001;"""
CONNECTION2.Execute "CREATE TABLE [Test.csv] ([aa] VARCHAR(200), [bb] VARCHAR(200))"

Dim RECORDSET2
Set RECORDSET2 = WScript.CreateObject("ADODB.Recordset")
RECORDSET2.Open "SELECT * FROM [Test.csv]", CONNECTION2, 2, 2

Do Until RECORDSET1.EOF
    RECORDSET2.AddNew
    Dim i
    For i = 0 To RECORDSET1.Fields.Count - 1
        WScript.Echo RECORDSET1.Fields(i).Value
        RECORDSET2.Fields(i).Value = RECORDSET1.Fields(i).Value
    Next
    RECORDSET2.Update
    RECORDSET1.MoveNext
Loop
```

Comment: You may want to switch to PowerShell and the [ImportExcel module](https://www.powershellgallery.com/packages/ImportExcel) for something like this.

Comment: can u please explain it clearly.I am a beginner

Comment: Please check the [project documentation](https://github.com/dfinke/ImportExcel).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Got a solution and worked fine for me

```
ObjExcelFile_CSVSource.SaveAs CSVFile,42
```